# Oracle Table got dropped by Hibernate; flashed back to DB from recycle bin. Getting error "SQL Error: 942, SQLState: 42000"

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Working on Spring Data + JPA + Hibernate + Maven project.

Sequence of events:

1. I had a working code using the above which used to query the `Favorites` Table using `JPARespository`. I added a line `props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto");` to the JPA Properties and the table Favorites gets dropped. Sheer panic!

   properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
2. I comment the code which caused the trouble. I request the DBA to recreate the table and she says it was in the recycle bin and she "flashed" it back.

   `private Map jpaProperties() {
           Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<String,Object>();
           properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                   environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
   //      properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
   //              environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
           properties.put("hibernate.show_sql",
                   environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
           properties.put("hibernate.format_sql",
                   environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
           return properties;
       }`

Database config method:

```
`@Primary
 @Bean(name = "dataSource")
 public DataSource dataSource() {
DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment
            .getRequiredProperty("rg.jdbc.driverClassName"));
dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("rg.jdbc.url"));
dataSource.setUsername(environment
            .getRequiredProperty("rg.jdbc.username"));
dataSource.setPassword(environment
            .getRequiredProperty("rg.jdbc.password"));
return dataSource;
}`
```

3. I can see the Table in SQL Developer using the same user credentials being used in the code. However, if I query the DB using `JPARepository` extended class using the `findAll()`.

I am getting the following error. I can see the Table in the DB, but not via the Java code.

Can somebody help me understand what does the above property do and why I can't see the table via the code, but can see it in SQL Developer? Also, how can I fix this?

```
Hibernate: 
select
    favorite0_.FAVORITE_ID as FAVORITE_ID1_1_,
    favorite0_.category as category2_1_,
    favorite0_.created as created3_1_,
    favorite0_.CREATED_BY as CREATED_BY4_1_,
    favorite0_.description as description5_1_,
    favorite0_.name as name6_1_,
    favorite0_.OBJECT_TYPE_ID as OBJECT_TYPE_ID7_1_ 
from
    FAVORITES favorite0_
2017-09-22 02:21:20 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 942, SQLState: 42000
2017-09-22 02:21:20 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Sep 22, 2017 1:24:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/RG-NG] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:776)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3867)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1502)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2117)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
```

Comment: `props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.autopdate");` is not correct, please post the actual code. For one `put` expects two parameters, and the property would be `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`.

Comment: are you using the same oracle user for both code and SQL Developer connections?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you are correct. I have updated the code snippet. properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));

Comment: @Zeromus Yes. Same Oracle user. I've restarted the tomcat several times as well.

Comment: suggestion: set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to validate so you can validate schema before program execution

Comment: @Zeromus Adding this property caused the table to drop. Is this expected behavior? I am new to Hibernate.    

`properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));`

Comment: @Anoop Hallimala depends what the environment.getRequi‌​redProperty is:
Create/Create-drop both recreate db schema, update will update the schema, validate will throw exception if schema and entities mapping differ

Comment: @Zeromus Could you pls tell me how to validate the schema? I can try that and come back with the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @CyrilleMODIANO and @Zeromus for pointing me in the right direction. I resolved the issue.

There were 2 issues:

1) I turned on validation of schema.

```
properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", SchemaAutoTooling.VALIDATE.name().toLowerCase());
```

This told me there was a problem with one of the Entity classes and this annotation was absent for variable annotated with @Id

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

2) The datasource injection was getting messed up. DB1's datasource object was getting injected into DB2's PU.

Adding a Qualifier and giving it unique names fixed it.

```
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "rgDataSource")
    public DataSource rgDataSource()

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "rgEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("rgDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
```

Comment: This is it. I was getting the error "SqlExceptionHelper ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" along with "SQL Error: 942, SQLState: 42000" and was clueless unless I enabled the schema validation in hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you had previously privileges on the table bu because it was dropped your privileges are gone, ask your DBA to restore the privileges on the table.

Comment: I am trying to just to findAll(). Will this be affected? The error says the table doesn't exist. I can always ask the DBA to restore privileges, but want to make sure its the right request as quite a few people are copied :)

Comment: if you dont have privilege to see the table than of course that error will be thrown... but you said that you can see the table with same user

Comment: this error usually means you don't have enough privileges to see the table so oracle throw an exception saying the table doesn't exist.
Are you sure you use the same account in SQL Developer and  Hibernate, if you can see the table with SQL Developer you should be able to list it through Hibernate.

Comment: @Zeromus Yes. I just queried the table in SQL Developer, after reconnecting. I can surely see the table with all the data.

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO Absolutely.I am using connecting to 2 schemas in the codebase and I verified that I was using the right entitymanager while debugging. I restarted tomcat and reconnected to the DB in SQL Developer. I can still see the table in SQLDeveloper with all the data, but get the same error from the code. Is there any code snippet which will tell me the privileges? I've also updated the stacktrace in the code above.

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO, I am using Java Config. I've updated the question with the JPAProperties. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: where is the connection information to the database? this is where I suspect something wrong.